# Mouseover not working on image_tag

Tags: onmouseover

I want to show a different image on the mouse over event.
This is the code I have (haml):

```
  = image_tag(product.photos.first.asset.thumb.url, :onMouseover=> "this.src=product.photos.second.asset.thumb.url'", :onMouseout=> "this.src=product.photos.first.asset.thumb.url'")
```

but I keep getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on that line.

Any suggestions of what am I doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: i believe the function is `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`
though I am unfamiliar with HAML

Comment: Should you have those extra back ticks in the url? **.url(')"**

Comment: @Okuma.Scott thank you so much. what a silly thing and you just saved my day!

Comment: No problem. Easy to miss a thing like that.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
      = image_tag(product.photos.first.asset.thumb.url, :onMouseover=> "this.src='#{product.photos.second.asset.thumb.url}'", :onMouseout=> "this.src='#{product.photos.first.asset.thumb.url}'")
```